# Invalid length parameter passed to LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Tags: c#, t-sql

I got this error mess "Invalid length parameter passed to LEFT or SUBSTRING function" from this below. Anyone can give me a hint what cause this, and how I can solve it?

```
string cmdText = @"Declare  @SqlString nvarchar(2500)
, @AreaDelimiter char(1)
, @AreaFilter nvarchar(max);
Select @AreaDelimiter = ','    
If (@AreaName Not Like '*')
Begin
    Set @AreaName = @AreaName + @AreaDelimiter
    Set @AreaFilter = ''

    While LEN(@AreaName) > 0
    Begin
        If (Len(@AreaFilter) > 0)
        Begin
            Set @AreaFilter = @AreaFilter + ' Or Area Like ''' + 
               LTRIM(SubString(@AreaName, 1, 
                   CharIndex(@AreaDelimiter, @AreaName) - 1)) + '%'''
        End
        Else
        Begin
            Set @AreaFilter = 'Area Like ''' + 
               LTRIM(SubString(@AreaName, 1, 
                   CharIndex(@AreaDelimiter, @AreaName) - 1)) + '%'''
        End

        Select @AreaName = SUBSTRING(@AreaName, CharIndex(@AreaDelimiter,
             @AreaName) + 1, Len(@AreaName))
    End
End"
```

> this code above continues with the else statement and the others operations who works :)

And this is my C# code:

```
string area = "AREA1,AREA2,AREA3";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(domain.getDecryptedSqlConnectionString(domain.name + passPhrase)))
  {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
    {

      System.Globalization.CultureInfo cInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR");
      DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(startDate, cInfo);
      DateTime da = DateTime.Parse(endDate, cInfo);
      cmd.Parameters.Add("Interval", SqlDbType.Int).Value = interval;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("IntervalUnit", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = intervalUnit;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value =  dt.ToShortDateString();
      cmd.Parameters.Add("EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = da.ToShortDateString();
      cmd.Parameters.Add("tbName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = domain.alarmTableName;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("AreaName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = area; 
      using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
      {
        using (DataTable tb = new DataTable())
        {
          try
          {
            conn.Open();
            adapter.Fill(tb);
            return tb;
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
            return tb;
          }
          finally
          {
            conn.Close();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

SOLVED, I JUST CHANGE

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("AreaName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = area;
```

FOR

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("AreaName", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1).Value = area;
```

Comment: Could `CharIndex(@AreaDelimiter, @AreaName) - 1)` be negative?

Comment: couldnt, but i have no idea how to fix it

Comment: Please would you edit your question to include sample data for `@AreaName` and `@AreaDelimiter` which works and sample data which doesn't work.

Comment: i put the sample values of '@AreaName' and '@AreaDelimiter'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the error with

```
DECLARE @AreaName VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE @AreaDelimiter CHAR(1);
DECLARE @AreaFilter VARCHAR(100);

SET @AreaName='AREA1,AREA2,AREA3,area4,area5';
SET @AreaDelimiter=',';
```

Notice that the declaration of @AreaName is not long enough for the data - check your declaration.

Also, if the string for @AreaName has come from user input, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

EDIT:

All your SQL parameter names need to start with `@`, e.g. `@AreaName`, and you must match up the `SqlDbType` between your C# code and the SQL code.

You shouldn't be using

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value =  dt.ToShortDateString();
```

instead it should be

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value =  dt;
```

because `dt` is already a DateTime.

Comment: i have this `Declare @SqlString nvarchar(2500)
 , @AreaDelimiter char(1)
 , @AreaFilter nvarchar(max);` and the @AreaName come from checkboxes

Comment: i get the value doing something like this `cmd.Parameters.Add("AreaName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = area;`

Comment: @Andriusha What is the declaration for @AreaName? You showed the others, but *that* is the one which I can get the error with. If you do not give it a length, it defaults to 1.

Comment: the `@AreaName` is not declared on sql, i add this in C# code after intance a SqlCommand object named cmd. the declaration of `@AreaName` is that command above.

Comment: @Andriusha What's the C# code you use to add the @AreaName parameter? If you are using .AddWithValue, can you try changing it to `.Add("@AreaName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1, yourAreaNameVariable)`?

Comment: i using this `.Add("AreaName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = area;` i try to change to this `.Add("AreaName", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1, area);` but not worked. And why `-1` value in the size?

Comment: @Andriusha `-1` for the size is the same as NVARCHAR(MAX). In what way did it not work: was it the same error or different?

Comment: `{"The parameterized query '(@Interval int,@IntervalUnit varchar(3),@StartDate datetime,@End' expects the parameter '@AreaName', which was not supplied."}`

Comment: @Andriusha `.Add("AreaName", ` - you're missing the `@` for `@AreaName`.

Comment: @Andriusha Please edit your question to show the C# code which is calling your stored procedure and also the declaration (the `AS` part) of your stored procedure (it should have an `@AreaName NVarChar(MAX)` in it).

Comment: @Andriusha I edited my answer; I don't know if you get notified of that, hence this comment.

Comment: I fixed, worked with the code `.Add("AreaName", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1).Value = area;`

Comment: @Andriusha Phew! Happy I could help you fix it :)